# jsPDF non Latin letters

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable, react-pdf

I'm trying to create a table with jsPDF , my table contain non Latin words and they come out look like gibberish.

I tried add the language and changing the font but nothing worked.

doc.addFont('notosans-fontface')

doc.setFont('notosans-fontface')
doc.setLanguage('ar')